# Comparing JSON response of

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, compare

Good morning everyone. I have a service which returns me a JSON response (something like below):

```
{
  "sessionid": "AQIC5wM2LY4SfcytTIcteNkTtCVrE8A-AS7VR*",
  "Customers": [
    {
      "id": "4193942846",
      "firstname": "Anto",
      "lastname": "Paul",
      "customertype": "ph",
      "companyCode": "ABCD",
    },
    {
      "id": "4193942236",
      "firstname": "Dimple",
      "lastname": "Paul",
      "customertype": "ph",
      "companyCode": "AB",
    }
  ],
  "Status": "ACTIVE",
  "serviceStatus": "SUCCESS",

  "Addresses": {
    "Address": [
      {
    "type": "M",
        "addr1": "11011, main st",
        "addr2": "Apt. 2",
        "zipcode": "11011"
      }
     ]
    } 
}
```

The above structure varies based on the input I pass to the service. So, I cant contruct one class to deserialize the response. I need to compare (attribute-attribute comparison) this response to a response I already have with me (in a different place).

I tried to do it with dynamic class in C# but no luck so far. Could someone share a better,working approach? Thank you.

Comment: did you try any JSON library which gives you generic objects?

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: How do I recursively compare these two objects?

            JObject jo2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultstr);
            JObject jo3 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(expectedstr);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect differences between two json files in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034224/detect-differences-between-two-json-files-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JToken.DeepEquals` like this:

```
var response = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
var goldenStandard = JObject.Parse(goldenStandardJson);
if (JToken.DeepEquals(response, goldenStandard))
{
    // the two JSONs have the same data 
}
```

Comment: The same thing suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815006/compare-two-jobjects-or-jarray

Answer (score 0):

Try Json.Net. It supports dynamic structures.
Here is a tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631586/Dynamic-types-with-JSON-NET

Comment: How do I recursively compare these two objects? 


JObject jo2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultstr); JObject jo3 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(expectedstr);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

https://jsonutil.codeplex.com/

```
var obj1 = JSONSerializer.Deserialize(jsontext1);
var obj2 = JSONSerializer.Deserialize(jsontext2);

bool Compare(object obj1, object obj2)
{
//if(obj1 is JSONObject && obj2 is JSONObject) 
//   => typecase and use jsonObj1.Members to iterate over members and compare values recursively

//if JSONArray, then iterate over items and compare

//if anything else... i.e. primitive then compare directly

//else return false;
}
```

Comment: Not a complete solution: instead of comparing the objects I would simply serialize them again and compare the results. This way you compare JSON strings that have been generated the same way - almost like a "canonical" form. HOWEVER, this assumes that the properties appear in the same order (you will have false negatives otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this JSON response one time, then you can use a dynamic JSON NET types.

But if you are using this JSON structure response some times, then it is preferable to make this response to a c# classes (objects), so you will have a very easy access to it's properties, you just have your c# objects and they have properties and you can simply approach to each field you wish (with intellisense). By the way, it is very easy to copy a JSON response to a C# classes (something like copy paste). Here is how to do that:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx